# logger usage, is parameterization better or using + to add arguments?

Tags: java, apache, log4j, log4j2

Which of the following is a better usage of logger?

1. Parametrize (log4j 2)

   ```
   logger.info("User {} has logged in using id {}", map.get("Name"), user.getId());`
   ```
2. Using + operator (log4j)

   ```
   logger.info("User"+ map.get("Name") +" has logged in using id " +user.getId());`
   ```

And why?

Comment: Why is it? I wan to know what happens when we parametrize. I don't seem to find the code for the parametrization one. Also, If for log4j logger.info allows only object and throwable. not multiple arguments.

Comment: Well, instead of using an ancient logging framework like `log4j`, use a better one (or preferably a logging facade like `SLF4J`).

Comment: Yeah.. I was editing someone else's code. They already had log4j. I will change it. Thanks. I knew parametrization is better, but didn't know the reason. Your answer explains that. Thanks @kayaman :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there were nothing else, the additional [StringBuilder shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator) that happen when using `+` would make using parameters the obvious choice.

Not to mention that when concatenating the values, the `toString()` method of all the parameters will be called even if the logging level isn't enabled, meaning that you're wasting CPU to build a String that will never be logged.
This would have an (albeit minor) effect if there are lots of `debug()` statements, when DEBUG level is usually disabled in production environments.

Comment: From a 2021 perspective the first alternative would have prevented Log4j from expanding user supplied lookups (cf. [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228)).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz actually even the parameterized version is susceptible to that, which is what makes it so dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

[Parameterized messages](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/messages.html) avoid formatting the text until Log4j is certain that the message will be logged. This allows you to avoid surrounding the logger.debug(...) call with checks like `if (logger.isDebugEnabled())...` which gives cleaner code.

> This answer is based on modern logging frameworks, not outdated ones like Log4J.

When you say "outdated" you must be talking about Log4j 1.x. As of 2014, Log4j 2 is the cutting edge open source logging framework. It takes some ideas from SLF4J, like [parameterized log messages](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.html), but adds a plugin system so you can easily add [custom appenders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j2/24220688#24220688), custom layouts and [custom lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745938/log4j2-2-1-custom-plugin-not-detected-by-packages-attribute/29761346#29761346). Furthermore Log4j 2 has support for [custom log levels](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html), [lambda expressions](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html#LambdaSupport) and the lock-free and very performant [Async Loggers](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Performance). To spice things up, from release 2.6 Log4j 2 is [garbage-free](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1270).

Kayaman is probably talking about Log4j 1, which has been [End of Life](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces) since August 2015.